# How to convert Oracle SDO table into ESRI shp file

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, esri, oracle-spatial

I am trying to convert my `SDO` table with `SDO_GEOM` data into an `ESRI .shp` file?

Context: I am trying to display the data in the SDO table as a graphics/drawing or whatever through Java and not  applications like Mapviewer or Mapbuilder. I thought it would be much easier to convert the SDO table into a shp file and display it using Geotools through a Mavel project in Eclipse

Comment: What software do you have available to you?

Comment: @Erica free ones that I can get